# Why did the es-MX date format change from Windows 7 to Windows 10?

Tags: c#, localization, formatting

Here's a unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Check_how_es_MX_displays_MMM()
{
    var originalCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    try
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-MX");
        var result = new DateTime(2015, 8, 6).ToString("MMM");
        Assert.AreEqual("ago", result);
    }
    finally
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = originalCulture;
    }
}
```

When I run this on Windows 7 it passes.  When I run this on a Windows 10 machine it fails:

```
Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<ago>. Actual:<ago.>.
```

I'm building against .NET 4.5.1 on both computers.

How could the "MMM" format string return "ago" in Windows 7 and "ago." in Widnows 10?  I had assumed it would always give me a 3 letter code for the month.

**Edit**

Some more reading indicates using MMM makes it look up the abbreviated month name from: `System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.AbbreviatedMonthNames`

**Edit 2**

Here is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240525/instances-of-cultureinfo-from-same-culture-changing-based-on-os) that deals with (I think) the same issue.

Comment: MMM does *not* generate a 3 letter month name, it generates the abbreviated month name.  Culture preferences *do* change, even faster than software development.  You'll need to update your test.

Comment: @HansPassant - yes, I'm realizing that.  Actually that test was just an illustration, the real test tells me that the implementation of our feature using this format won't work when we migrate to Windows 10.  Our requirement is a 3 character abbreviated Spanish month (gets printed on a fixed width field of a label).

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Windows 10 locale data comes from [CLDR - Common Locale Data Repository](http://cldr.unicode.org/)

More info:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnste/2015/08/29/locale-data-in-windows-10-cldr/