# c# datetime.parse handling german short names differently on different systems

Tags: .net, windows, datetime, server

I have a web application running on Windows Server 2008R2 and 2012R2 correctly. Now I migrated to Windows Server 2019. There is a problem converting some dates comming from the frontend system. The code used is as follows ...

```
pool.ExpirationDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse(routePrams["ddlExpirationDate"]), DateTimeKind.Local);
```

The value in the routePrams is "17 Mrz 2021". This runs ok on the old system but not on the new. On the Windows 2019 server I get the following exception ...

```
The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 3.
```

I also tried the following PowerShell test on both systems ...

```
[datetime]::Parse("17 Mrz 2021")
```

On the old systems this works ok an returns "Mittwoch, 17. März 2021 00:00:00". However on the new server it also returns the exception.

I checked the regional settings on all servers and it seems to be the same. Is there another setting affecting the conversion of dates?

What am I missing?

Comment: I tested on both systems. [datetime]::Parse("17 März 2021") is handled on all servers, but [datetime]::Parse("17 Mrz 2021") is only handeld correctly on the older servers (2008/12). Where can I tell the system to also handle the short month name correctly?

Comment: In Powershell using (Get-culture).DateTimeFormat is see that on the systems the following entry is different ... 
New: AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames    : {Jan., Feb., März, Apr....}
Old: AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames    : {Jan, Feb, Mrz, Apr...}

Comment: Have you tried using `ParseExact` instead of `Parse`? I never use the latter - always specify the format(s) you're expecting!

Comment: Yes, I do this. But this application was not developed by me and it is quite huge. So for the moment I need a way to configure this so it works on the new server. Changing this in the code would be quite a big task ...

Comment: Change the regional settings in Control Panel?

Comment: The regional setting is the same on all servers I checked this ... "German (Switzerland)" ...

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a difference how culture are handled on the differen OS versions. See here: [Why did the es-MX date format change from Windows 7 to Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39778369/why-did-the-es-mx-date-format-change-from-windows-7-to-windows-10).

Therefore I implemented a solution with ParseExact using the correct culture and this worked. The change in the application was not that big.

Thanks for the answers.