# C# DateTime.ParseExact not working with specific date

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing

I'm trying to convert a string containing date and time of an event to a DateTime object in C# using the following code:

```
try
{
    d = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "ddd MMM dd HH':'mm':'ss 'BST' yyyy", null);
}
catch (Format exception) 
{
}
```

When the string "date" is equal to "Fri Oct 13 09:30:50 BST 2023", the code works fine but when I set the date string to "Thu Sep 28 13:57:58 BST 2023", it throws the following exception:

> System.FormatException: 'String 'Thu Sep 28 13:57:58 BST 2023' was not
> recognized as a valid DateTime.'

Any idea why this may be?

Comment: I would modify one detail at a time in the failing string to narrow it down. The 24-hour clock stands out as a possibility.

Comment: 1) What culture are you using 2) What framework/runtime version and OS?

Comment: `MMM` specifies the [abbreviated name of the month](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#MMM_Specifier) I'm assuming you're using the en-gb locale as you're using BST where the abbreviated month name for September is "Sept" not "Sep" as you're expecting.

Comment: Hmm, interesting... It would seem that the abbreviated month names come from the OS and is inconsistent (at least between different versions of Windows)! Probably not a great idea to rely on it for parsing dates coming from other systems. - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76324713/592958

Comment: BTW if you wish to continue parsing Sep, you can enable NLS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77192077/6196568

Comment: Simple check: construct an object representing that date time and then format it using that format string. Then compare to your actual input. Are there differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to specify *CultureInfo* instead of *null*

```
var date = "Thu Sep 28 13:57:58 BST 2023";
try
{
    var d = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "ddd MMM dd HH':'mm':'ss 'BST' yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);                  
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

and be careful if you specify wrong week abbreviations(like "Fri Sep 28 13:57:58 BST 2023") you will get System.FormatException

Comment: `TryParseExact` would be a good idea, rather than blindly swallowing exceptions.